# Convert struct to map in Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to convert one dataset which declares a column to have a certain `struct` type (eg. `struct<x: string, y: string>`) to a `map<string, string>` type. And I would like to do it in SQL, possibly without using UDFs.

**UPDATE**:

> My requirement is also that the transformation is done generically without any prior knowledge of the struct keys (in my problem I am getting data in a complex JSON, and I don't want to keep that complexity in the schema).

Example input data:

```sql
WITH input (struct_col) as (
    select named_struct('x', 'valX', 'y', 'valY') union all
    select named_struct('x', 'valX1', 'y', 'valY2')
)
select *
from input
```

expected output is a column of type `map<string, string>`

| struct_col:map<string, string> |
| --- |
| {"x":"valX","y":"valY"} |
| {"x":"valX1","y":"valY2"} |

---

**UPDATE:**

So far I managed to find this very convoluted solution which works only with Spark >= `3.1.0` (because of [`json_object_keys`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/sql/index.html#json_object_keys) function). Would be so nice to just be able to cast a struct to a map

```sql
WITH input (struct_col) as (
    select named_struct('x', 'valX', 'y', 'valY') union all
    select named_struct('x', 'valX1', 'y', 'valY2')
)
select transform_values(
       map_from_arrays(
               json_object_keys(to_json(struct_col)),
               json_object_keys(to_json(struct_col))
           ),
        (k, v) -> get_json_object(to_json(struct_col), '$.' || k))
from input
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have found a way to do it which requires one roundtrip of serializing and parsing a json using the [`to_json`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#to_json) and [`from_json`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#from_json) functions. The trick is that the `from_json` also takes a schema argument where I use the `map<string, string>` type.

Also, this solution should work with spark < 3.x

```sql
WITH input (struct_col) as (
    select named_struct('x', 'valX', 'y', 'valY')
    union all
    select named_struct('x', 'valX1', 'y', 'valY2')
) 
select from_json(to_json(struct_col), 'map<string, string>') as map_col
from input;
```

Answer (score 0):

What about

```py
create_map('struct_col.x', 'struct_col.valX', 'struct_col.y', 'struct_col.valY')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Maybe I did not mention that in the question, but I meant an arbitrary, possibly huge struct. I am trying to get rid of complexity by using a map and explicitly listing the fields and values is not an option.

Comment: Can you add that to the question. How do you distinguish between the map and key columns? is there a suffix?

Comment: I updated the questions (thanks). What do you mean by _ how do you distinguish between the map and key columns_? I don't understand the question.

Comment: you have  struct with many columns you want into make a key-value pair, do you mind which order they're paired up? if yes what is it

Comment: I would not rely on the map entry order - do they even preserve the order? Just like in a hashmap I would only get elements by key or iterate over the whole map in arbitrary order.